# Android Studio - Plugin Too Old (Gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Quite new to Android Dev, and I've been getting a strange error recently. I've searched online, and nothing seems to do the trick, so while I understand that this might be a duplicate question, no other previously asked question was able to offer me a working solution.

When I make a new project in Android Studio (version 2.2 Preview 1), I get bombarded with the error:

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "84c9986024dd3d7a4767dc5c38710ff1b96f1a21"
```

With two options: "Fix plugin version and sync project" which seems to do nothing. Upon clicking. And "Open File" which just opens the "build.gradle" file.
In my settings, I have Android Studio set to use the default gradle wrapper. I even set the distributionurl to the newest gradle version, but apparently even that is "too old"...

I have no idea what's causing this problem.

Another peculiar thing I've noticed is that in the project panel, it seems that my project doesnt look as it should.

The project in question looks like this:

[image]

Whereas, I understand that it should look more like this:

[image]

Again, no idea what's going on... I'm pretty new to Android Studio, but I'll do my best to answer any questions you may have.

Comment: *It should look more like this* - Actually, no, that would be just a standard layout for a Java project, not an Android project. The first image is how it should look

Comment: The newest version of Gradle is 3.0, yes? I don't think the Android Gradle plugin supports that yet

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried everything from 2.14.x up to 3.0. same error.

Comment: I'm not sure that the error is related to the Gradle version (which should be 2.14.x), but instead the Android Gradle Plugin (in the top-level build.gradle), https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Comment: how would i go about fixing the issue then?
Where would i be able to download the gradle .pom and .jar?

Comment: There are no .pom files, this is Gradle, not Maven. And there is no JAR file, either. In your top-level `build.gradle`, there should be a line that looks like `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'`, and that 2.1.3 is the plugin version

Comment: and in changing that, it gives me an error saying it cant find the 2.14.1 pom and jar files.

Comment: And that is the value from the `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` file?

Comment: oh sorry i see now. 
in the `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` i have `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`
and in the `build.gradle` i have: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'`

now it looks like its telling me that the version I have of android studio is too old. (Version 2.2 preview 1)? but then if i check for updates, it says I have the most recent version of AS

Comment: I use IntelliJ, so I can't speak for AS, but I use both those versions, and can sync my project fine. I do have "Use default gradle wrapper" in my preferences, though

Comment: well apparently all of the sudden it decided to work. I have no idea how I fixed it or how it fixed itself. but something happened.

Comment: Well, that's good :) I think since you are using a Preview build of Android Studio. It might want you to be using a 2.2 beta build of the Gradle plugin

Comment: perhaps. thanks for your help, and dealing with my not knowning much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I believe the message may be because you have a 2.2 Preview build of Android Studio, it may want you to use a [beta build](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) of the Android Gradle Plugin.

Note: This is **not** related to the version of Gradle. The latest supported version of Gradle is 2.14.1, which you can check the [Android Studio Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/index.html), and also [here](http://tools.android.com/recent).

From that first link, what I find most people don't understand.

> The plugin runs independent of Android Studio so the plugin and the Gradle build system can be updated independently of Android Studio

Or [Configuring your build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html), which explains why they are separated.

> you can build your Android apps from within Android Studio, the command line on your machine, or on machines where Android Studio is not installed (such as continuous integration servers). If you are not using Android Studio, you can learn how to build and run your app from the command line. The output of the build is the same whether you are building a project from the command line, on a remote machine, or using Android Studio.